# hide embedded youtube video's controls after mouseout

Tags: html, youtube

I embededd a video on a my localhost page, but when I pause the video...the controls dont disappear.

this is my code

```
   <div class='videoPlayerContainer'>
    <iframe  id="videoPlayer" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $w;?>?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

I want the controls to dissapear after the video is paused

```html
<div class='videoPlayerContainer'>
    <iframe  id="videoPlayer" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/NNVD5avTkIw?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are generally very limited with what you can control on an embedded player, [these are the available options](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) for the YouTube player.

Comment: I have already seen that list, but I couldnt find an option that enables the video to hide the controls after a pause was made...or a mouse out.